# Cache the last 50 event values and calculate maximum

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a program for my university project where I have to cache the latest 50 events and calculate the maximum value of a field retrieved from the event.

I am unsure as to what data structures need to be used to maintain the list which strictly allows the last 50 values and deletes the first one when the 51th arrives.

Do we have a Collections class that already provides the support for this?

I have used the `removeEldestEntry()` function for the LinkedHashMap in the past but it does not suit the requirement here.

Comment: you are probably looking for https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/stack_pop.htm

Comment: Stack won't let me control the number of elements I can have in the data structure. My data structure should strictly contain the last 50 entries

Comment: just do a check "while(stack.size()>50){stack.pop();} just after you add your object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can maintain the limit without ever having more than 50 elements in the stack, you just need to check size first and remove the oldest entry before you add a new one.  I'm not sure about the efficiency or the exact nature of the problem, but a thought...

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class SO_40856348 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

        // add 10 events to the stack (0-9)
        for(int x = 0; x<10; x++)
        {
            String event = "Event-"+x;
            System.out.println("At iteration [" + x + "] before adding event [" + event + "] stack contains:");
            printStack(stack);

            addEvent(stack, event);

            System.out.println("At iteration [" + x + "] after adding event [" + event + "] stack contains:");
            printStack(stack);
        }

        // dump events to console
        System.out.println("At the end of the program the stack contains:");
        printStack(stack);
    }

    public static void printStack(Stack<String> stack)
    {
        for(String e : stack)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void addEvent(Stack<String> stack, String event)
    {
        /* Never more than 5 events in the stack, if we current have 5, 
         * remove one and immediately add the next one.
         */
        if(stack.size() == 5)
        {
            // remove the oldest entry from the bottom of the stack
            stack.remove(0);
        }
        // push the newest entry onto the top of the stack
        stack.push(event);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps, or at least gives you an idea. :)